# How can I reduce the amount of data processed by my query on GoogleBigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis, data-cleaning, gdelt

I am (or at least trying to) conduct a sociological quantitative research through data analysis on the impact of the war in Ukraine on the public discourse regarding refugees. In order to do so, I've decided to get the data from the GDELT project and I thought that a sql query on BigQuery(where the GDELT  data is available) would be the first step to get a clean dataset to then analyze and visualize in Rstudio. As I only want to consider articles published in Italy from december the 31st 2021 to december the 31st 2023, having refugees as the main theme, I devised the following SQL code, but BigQuery says that it will process 1000GB of data when run and obv my pc and my wallet cannot afford it. Anyone has any suggestion?
Here's the code

```
SELECT 
  GKGRECORDID,
  CAST(SUBSTR(CAST(Date AS STRING), 1, 4) AS INT64) AS Year,
  CAST(SUBSTR(CAST(Date AS STRING), 5, 2) AS INT64) AS Month,
  CAST(SUBSTR(CAST(Date AS STRING), 7, 2) AS INT64) AS Day,
  DocumentIdentifier AS ArticleURL,
  V2Tone
FROM 
  `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned`
WHERE 
  Date BETWEEN 20211231000000 AND 20231231235959
  AND LOWER(DocumentIdentifier) LIKE '%.it/%'
  AND (REGEXP_CONTAINS(Themes, r'REFUGEES') OR 
       REGEXP_CONTAINS(Themes, r'SOC_REFUGEECAMP') OR 
       REGEXP_CONTAINS(Themes, r'WB_1601_REFUGEE_SUPPORT') OR 
       REGEXP_CONTAINS(Themes, r'WB_2665_REFUGEE_RESETTLEMENT') OR 
       REGEXP_CONTAINS(Themes, r'WB_2731_REFUGEE_WORKERS') OR 
       REGEXP_CONTAINS(Themes, r'WB_2894_REFUGEES_AND_JOBS'))
LIMIT 100000
```

Thank you!

I can't run such a big query

Comment: the GDELT 2.0 GKG table contains 353 million records totaling 3.6TB , that's whjat the website says

Comment: Yeah, just looked it up. Ouch. Those tables are partitioned by _PARTITIONTIME though. Looks like that was very deliberate design for this exact case. https://blog.gdeltproject.org/announcing-partitioned-gdelt-bigquery-tables/ . Have you tried adding: _PARTITIONTIME >= TIMESTAMP("2021-12-31") and _PARTITIONTIME <= TIMESTAMP("2023-12-31") to your query?

Comment: This helps! The data amount got reduced to 156gb, thanks a lot! Do you have any other idea on how I can reduce it even more?

Comment: A partition is, very loosely described, kind of like how a US history textbook might be organized by decade. Everything talking about the 1960's will be together, everything talking about the 1840's will be together. Then there are some supplementary information that tells the database where everything is, like an index in the back of the book. If you know an event happened in 1963, you don't have to read the whole book. You can beeline right to the chapter.

Comment: If you can track down some metadata or tech specs on that table it'd help. LOWER(DocumentIdentifier) LIKE '%.it/%' is generally not a good pattern, because the database has to read every record and evaluate the function. If there is a specific list of Italy extensions and that can be written as an equality conditions that can help the database use statistics.

Comment: I can attach the ID to access the gdelt gkg partitioned table on. BigQuery, so that you can see the details and a preview. Yeah, I'm not really sure about that '%.it%' pattern, but I don't know how else I can filter out the articles in order to get only the ones published in Italian. I'll also attach the link to the GDELT Codebook so that you have a better idea of the columns. Thanks again for the help!  This is the ID of the table: gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned and this is the codebook http://data.gdeltproject.org/documentation/GDELT-Event_Codebook-V2.0.pdf

Comment: Here's also a link to the ufficial GDELT website with some  BigQuery demos! https://blog.gdeltproject.org/a-compilation-of-gdelt-bigquery-demos/